# Why I cannot use allocated pointer in this case?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, c-strings

```
char    *ft_strjoin(int size, char **strs, char *sep)
{
    int     full_length;
    int     index;
    char    *read_head;
    char    *string;

    if (size == 0)
        return ((char *)malloc(sizeof(char)));
    full_length = ft_compute_final_length(strs, size, ft_str_length(sep));
    if (!(string = (char *)malloc((full_length + 1) * sizeof(char))))
        return (0);
    read_head = string;
    index = 0;
    while (index < size)
    {
        ft_strcpy(read_head, strs[index]);
        read_head += ft_str_length(strs[index]);
        if (index < size - 1)
        {
            ft_strcpy(read_head, sep);
            read_head += ft_str_length(sep);
        }
        index++;
    }
    *read_head = '\0';
    return (string);
}
```

When I saw others code I wonder the part of this.

```
read_head = string;
```

I change the code that use only allocated pointer.

In this case

```
string
```

So the error occures that "pointer being freed was not allocated"

I can't understand that Why do I have to use another pointer to point another pointer?

Is it happend because that to strcpy pointer and allocated pointer are different?

Comment: I don't see any pointer being freed in your code, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) featuring the *changed* code that produces the error you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this statement

```
if (size == 0)
        return ((char *)malloc(sizeof(char)));
```

does not make a sense because the function returns a pointer to a non-initialized memory. Maybe you mean

```
if (size == 0)
        return (char *)calloc( 1, sizeof(char));
```

That is the function will return a pointer to an empty string.

Within the function the pointer `read_head` is being changed as for example in this statement

```
read_head += ft_str_length(strs[index]);
```

That is after using it such a way it will not point to the initially allocated memory. As it is seen from this statement

```
*read_head = '\0';
```

after the while loop the pointer points to the terminating zero of the built string.

So using it in a call of free will issue the error you got.

So this statement

```
read_head = string;
```

allows to preserve the address of the allocated dynamically memory in the pointer `string` and to use the intermediate pointer `read_head` that will be changed..

Answer (score 2):

> Why I cannot use allocated pointer in this case?

The reason that you can't use `string` directly but have to use the extra `read_head` variable is because you change `read_head` in the loop (i.e. `read_head += ...`). If you did that directly on `string` you would be in problems because you need to know the `malloc`ed value of `string` so that you can call `free` later on.

Simple example **of wrong code**:

```
char *string = malloc(...);
string += someValue;        // Change the value of string
free(string);  <-------- ERROR because the value of string changed
```

Simple example **of good code**:

```
char *string = malloc(...);
char *read_head = string;   // Give read_headthe same value as string
read_head += someValue;     // Change the value of read_head 
free(string);  <-------- FINE because the value of string did NOT change
```